# ETL onto EMR for Impala

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl

We have an EMR cluster running Impala.

We have lots of data in DynamoDB and S3.

What is the best/recomended way of getting data into our HDFS EMR cluster from Dynamo (So that I can get it into Impala afterwards)? Should I write a python script that imports `boto` and some HDFS library to do it, should I learn PIG directly, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to take a small learning curve and get familiarization with `AWS Data Pipe`. By itself it is a very good service; the best thing is that it is fully managed and interoperates really well.

So without the involvement of additional 3rd Party Tools [ ETL ] suite and by extension without running additional EC2 instances; you get to **link, schedule, transfer Data from DynamoDB to EMR.**

This link has necessary information in bit and pieces; but you can pick up ideas from here and there and create your DynamoDB to EMR link [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-part2.html]

Comment: OK based on your recommendation I'm going to learn the pipeline and assume I can get data out of Dynamo with it onto HDFS in EMR.

Answer (score 0):

I use alteryx for ETL . I would recommend using it. It has pretty cool analytics package as well.